# Preventing AJAX behavior on links on jQuery Mobile for all links

Tags: jquery-mobile

How do I prevent jQuery Mobile's ajax behavior on all links? I know that this behavior can be disabled for a single link by adding the `data-ajax='false'` or `rel='external'` attributes to a the link, but is there a global attribute I can use to disable this functionality for all links without marking up my whole document or applying the attribute via javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 1.1, jQuery Mobile added support for using `data-ajax="false"` on a parent container which allows you to exclude a large number of links from the AJAX navigation system. This avoids the need to add this attribute to every link in a container. To activate this functionality, `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled` must be set to true because this feature adds overhead we don't want to enable by default.

[jQuery Mobile Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/links/)